# Disable Direct IP Access on VestaCP NGINX + Apache2

Tags: nginx

In the current version of VestaCP once you install it and access your server's IP it will return the latest website you've added in VestaCP.

This is bad on so many levels and I consider it a vulnerability.
An example is you are hosting a website and hiding it using a service like Cloudflare, an attacker could find your server's IP using a service like Shodan.io and DDoS you even though you are using Cloudflare.
Another example is you are hosting an anonymous TOR website but people can find the IP of your server using Shodan.io thus destroying the *anonymous* part.

I would like to make it so it returns a 444 response when you directly access the server via its IP.

Currently, this is how the NGINX config works using VestaCP:

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
# Server globals
user                    nginx;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    65535;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;


# Worker config
events {
        worker_connections  1024;
        use                 epoll;
        multi_accept        on;
}


http {
    # Main settings
    sendfile                        on;
    tcp_nopush                      on;
    tcp_nodelay                     on;
    client_header_timeout           1m;
    client_body_timeout             1m;
    client_header_buffer_size       2k;
    client_body_buffer_size         256k;
    client_max_body_size            256m;
    large_client_header_buffers     4   8k;
    send_timeout                    30;
    keepalive_timeout               60 60;
    reset_timedout_connection       on;
    server_tokens                   off;
    server_name_in_redirect         off;
    server_names_hash_max_size      512;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size   512;


    # Log format
    log_format  main    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request '
                        '"$status" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    log_format  bytes   '$body_bytes_sent';
    #access_log          /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    access_log off;


    # Mime settings
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;


    # Compression
    gzip                on;
    gzip_comp_level     9;
    gzip_min_length     512;
    gzip_buffers        8 64k;
    gzip_types          text/plain text/css text/javascript text/js text/xml application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml application/xml+rss application/x-font-ttf image/svg+xml font/opentype;
    gzip_proxied        any;
    gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.";


    # Proxy settings
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass_header   Set-Cookie;
    proxy_connect_timeout   90;
    proxy_send_timeout  90;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;
    proxy_buffers       32 4k;


    # Cloudflare https://www.cloudflare.com/ips
    set_real_ip_from   103.21.244.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   103.22.200.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   103.31.4.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   104.16.0.0/12;
    set_real_ip_from   108.162.192.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from   131.0.72.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   141.101.64.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from   162.158.0.0/15;
    set_real_ip_from   172.64.0.0/13;
    set_real_ip_from   173.245.48.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from   188.114.96.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from   190.93.240.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from   197.234.240.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   198.41.128.0/17;
    #set_real_ip_from   2400:cb00::/32;
    #set_real_ip_from   2606:4700::/32;
    #set_real_ip_from   2803:f800::/32;
    #set_real_ip_from   2405:b500::/32;
    #set_real_ip_from   2405:8100::/32;
    #set_real_ip_from   2c0f:f248::/32;
    #set_real_ip_from   2a06:98c0::/29;
    real_ip_header     CF-Connecting-IP;


    # SSL PCI Compliance
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers        "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";


    # Error pages
    error_page          403          /error/403.html;
    error_page          404          /error/404.html;
    error_page          502 503 504  /error/50x.html;


    # Cache settings
    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=2 keys_zone=cache:10m inactive=60m max_size=1024m;
    proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri $cookie_user";
    proxy_temp_path  /var/cache/nginx/temp;
    proxy_ignore_headers Expires Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_502;
    proxy_cache_valid any 1d;


    # Cache bypass
    map $http_cookie $no_cache {
        default 0;
        ~SESS 1;
        ~wordpress_logged_in 1;
    }


    # File cache settings
    open_file_cache          max=10000 inactive=30s;
    open_file_cache_valid    60s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors   off;


    # Wildcard include
    include             /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

As you can see at the end of the file it includes every file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ that ends with .conf

There are three notable files in the /etc/nginx/conf.d/ directory: 92.222.36.xxx.conf, status.conf and vesta.conf

92.222.36.xxx.conf: (By default this is the public IP of the server and I've removed the last three numbers to hide my server's IP)

```
server {
    listen       92.222.36.xxx:80 default;
    server_name  _;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/92.222.36.xxx.log main;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://92.222.36.xxx:8080;
   }
}
```

As far as I understand this is used as an default and it forwards all the HTTP connections to Apache2 for which there isn't a define server_name.

status.conf:

```
server {
    listen       127.0.0.1:8084 default;
    server_name  _;
    server_name_in_redirect  off;
    location / {
        stub_status on;
        access_log   off;
   }
}
```

Used internally for checking the status of NGINX.

```
include /home/admin/conf/web/exampledomain.net.nginx.conf;
include /home/admin/conf/web/exampledomain.net.nginx.ssl.conf;
```

For each new site you add it creates these files.

This is how those files look like:

exampledomain.net.nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen      92.222.36.xxx:80;
    server_name exampledomain.net www.exampledomain.net;
    error_log  /var/log/httpd/domains/exampledomain.net.error.log error;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://92.222.36.xxx:8080;
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|svg|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|odt|ods|odp|odf|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|mp3|avi|mpeg|flv|html|htm)$ {
            root           /home/admin/web/exampledomain.net/public_html;
            access_log     /var/log/httpd/domains/exampledomain.net.log combined;
            access_log     /var/log/httpd/domains/exampledomain.net.bytes bytes;
            expires        max;
            try_files      $uri @fallback;
        }
    }

    location /error/ {
        alias   /home/admin/web/exampledomain.net/document_errors/;
    }

    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass      http://92.222.36.xxx:8080;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht    {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.svn/  {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.git/  {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.hg/   {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.bzr/  {return 404;}

    include /home/admin/conf/web/exampledomain.net.conf*;
}

server {
    listen      92.222.36.xxx:443;
    server_name exampledomain.net www.exampledomain.net;
    ssl         on;
    ssl_certificate      /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.exampledomain.net.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.exampledomain.net.key;
    error_log  /var/log/httpd/domains/exampledomain.net.error.log error;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      https://92.222.36.xxx:8443;
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|svg|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|odt|ods|odp|odf|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|mp3|avi|mpeg|flv|html|htm)$ {
            root           /home/admin/web/exampledomain.net/public_html;
            access_log     /var/log/httpd/domains/exampledomain.net.log combined;
            access_log     /var/log/httpd/domains/exampledomain.net.bytes bytes;
            expires        max;
            try_files      $uri @fallback;
        }
    }

    location /error/ {
        alias   /home/admin/web/exampledomain.net/document_errors/;
    }

    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass      https://92.222.36.xxx:8443;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht    {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.svn/  {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.git/  {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.hg/   {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.bzr/  {return 404;}

    include /home/admin/conf/web/snginx.exampledomain.net.conf*;
}
```

Now I have tried editing the 92.222.36.xxx.conf to this:

```
server {
    listen       92.222.36.xxx:80 default;
    server_name  _;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/92.222.36.xxx.log main;
    return 444;
}
```

And it did seem to work, I could access my website using the domain name and accessing it via the IP would result in a ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

But while accessing https://92.222.36.xxx/ it would still return the HTTPS version of my domain name, this is where my troubles started.

I tried doing this to 92.222.36.xxx.conf

```
server {
    listen       92.222.36.xxx:80 default;
    listen       92.222.36.xxx:443 default;
    server_name  _;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/92.222.36.xxx.log main;
    return 444;
}
```

While accessing my service using the IP using HTTPS it returned a ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR and while accessing using the domain name using HTTPS it also returns ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I've been trying to fix this for a few hours now but I couldn't.

I would be glad to receive some help in fixing this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution and it works perfectly.

This is how the working 92.222.36.xxx.conf looks like:

```
server {
    listen       92.222.36.xxx:80 default;
    server_name  _;
    return 444;
}

server {
    listen       92.222.36.xxx:443 default;
    server_name  _;
    ssl         on;
    ssl_certificate      /home/admin/conf/web/example.net.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/admin/conf/web/example.net.key;
    return 444;
}
```

The certicate and certificate key are dummies, make sure they don't leak domain names of other websites hosted on the server.